# Sharing TypeScript classes between client and server

Tags: node.js, typescript, amd, commonjs

I have a Node.js project written in TypeScript. In my project, I have a folder named "public" which contains the client side code & HTML and also a file named classes.ts which is supposed to be shared to the server side.

The problem is that I need to add "export" before the classes declaration in order to make them accessible in the server, but then in the browser I get this Error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

I found these questions:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5094,
[Setup a Typescript project with classes shared between client and server apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524206/setup-a-typescript-project-with-classes-shared-between-client-and-server-apps),
[Share module between client and server with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113995/share-module-between-client-and-server-with-typescript),
which suggests using commonjs in the server but amd in the client. The problem with this solution is that they have 3 different projects (server, client and shared) whereas I only have one project in which I use commonjs.
Another suggestion is:

> the other option, which is more convoluted and will require a post
>   build step to massage the code; if you can not use module loaders in
>   your client code, is to isolate all module dependencies in your server
>   code, then in the shared, they are just classes. Build the shared
>   files without --module, and no exports or imports, but all inside a
>   single namespace, say namespace MyApp { ... }; in your client code,
>   you include them directly, and emit using --out. in your server code,
>   you first emit the shared code to a single file, shared.js, and a
>   single .d.ts shared.d.ts, augment these with some code to export them
>   as a module, e.g. append exports = MyApp at the end of your shared.js
>   and shared.d.ts, then import them from your server code.

But I don't want to deal with updating .d.ts files all the time, and I'm also not sure it will work in one project.

Any suggestion how to make a TypeScript class accessible both in browser and server?

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is absolutely possible.

I have a project containing both SPA client application that runs in browser and server running in node.js that both share common typescript classes. For all of this I have just one tsconfig.json file (I am still not sure that this is the best approach but for now it works just fine)

Here are parts of my setup:

- Use modules (previously called external modules). No need for namespaces and d.ts files for your own modules.
- module = "commonjs" in tsconfig.
- On client side use System.js as module loader (this will solve your 'Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined'). You can use [angular2 5 min quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) as reference how to setup system.js.

It works like a charm.

Comment: I have a problem related to this topic and your solution. I posted another question for that problem and I also started a bounty for it. I'll be grateful if you manage to help me. This is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263627/loading-modules-in-typescript-using-system-js